# NERDTreeQuitOnOpen doesn't seem to work for NERDTree bookmarks

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have "let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 1" in my _vimrc (windows) and it works fine for NERDTree-o on a file.  However, when i use NERDTree-o on a Bookmark for a file the file opens in the main window and focus switches to it but the NERDTree window remains open.  How can i fix this so that the behaviour is the same for bookmarks as it is for a normal file in the NERDTree file system tree?